# React Native console.log old value useState

Tags: react-native

I'm having trouble with React Native showing wrong value for me. I wan't to show the value after an useState update. My goal is to pass the value to the parent component but right now it passes the opposite value (true when switch is off). What do I have to do to console.log the right value after a useState update?

[Watch image for example here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2JsPy.jpg)

Comment: Please read [ask], in particular the bit about providing a [mcve].

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The useState hook is somewhat asynchronous (although you cannot `wait` for it).

Try using a useEffect:

```js
useEffect(() => {
   console.log(isEnabled)
}, [isEnabled]) // Array of dependencies: when any of these value changes, the function in the useEffect will re-run
```

More information here:

- https://dev.to/shareef/react-usestate-hook-is-asynchronous-1hia
- https://javascript.plainenglish.io/why-you-shouldnt-always-use-usestate-658994693018

Answer (score 1):

The `Change` function will always "see" the state value that existed at the time of running the function. This is not because of asynchronicity per se (state updates are actually sync) but because of how closures work. It does feel like it is async though.

The state value will properly update in the background, but it won't be available in the "already-running" function. You can find more info [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74582163/react-context-api-current/74582268#).

The way I see your handler implemented though:

```
    const handleChange = () => {
      setIsEnabled(!isEnabled) // you do not need updater function, you can directly reference the state
      triggerParentMethod(!isEnabled); // then you can also directly call the parent function here
    }
```

I recommend this as this way you will notify the parent immediately on user click instead of waiting for the state to be set and then notifying the parent in the next render cycle (in the effect), which should be unnecessary.

Answer (score 0):

State updates in React are asynchronous, meaning that React does not wait for the state to be updated before executing the next line of code. In your case, the state update `setIsEnabled(...)` is not finished before `console.log(isEnabled)` is run, and therefore it returns the old value.

Just put the `console.log(isEnabled)` outside the function for it to print the update correctly. The component `SetupSwitch` is re-rendered when the state `isEnabled` is updated, which means it prints the console.log of the updated variable again.

```js
...
console.log(isEnabled);
const Change = () => {
...
```

Answer (score 0):

You will have to implement `useEffect` to view the changes.
`useState` is an asynchronous function it will go to the callback queue, meanwhile, the value will be consumed, so you need to trigger the action whenever the `count` changes. (for this example)

```
const [count, setCount] = useState(0);

useEffect(() => console.log(count), [count]);

setCurrPos(preevCount => prevCount + 1);
```