# React setState not changing value

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I am using react useState hook with a callback to update state.

However, the value stays at the initial value of `0`.

```js
const [currPos, setCurrPos] = useState(0);
console.log(`Current position is ${currPos}`);
// Update currPos so next keyPress is in the correct position
setCurrPos((prevState) => prevState + 1);
```

Logs always contain `Current position is 0`.

Code link: https://gitlab.com/mk851/wordle-clone/-/blob/main/src/App.tsx#L50

Comment: React state is changing its value and it's updating on click of keys. What exactly is the problem that you are facing or trying to do?

Comment: Within your repo `e.key` gives undefined ? can you try `e.target.getAttribute('data-key')`.

Comment: DecPK I am trying to access the updated value of currPos within `handleKeyPress` function but it is always 0 within this function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will have to implement `useEffect` to view the changes.
You're consoling the previous value, and `useState` is an asynchronous function it will go to the callback queue, meanwhile the value will be consoled, so you need to console the value whenever the `currPos` changes.

```
const [currPos, setCurrPos] = useState(0);

useEffect(() => console.log(currPos), [currPos]);

setCurrPos(prevCurrPos => prevCurrPos + 1);
```

Comment: Thanks I can see the correctly updated value in the console however, within the `handleKeyPress` function the value of currPos is always `0`?

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/reverent-bas-gt10ol

I have tried to repro the scenario, but it turns out to be working the correct way for me, have a look.

Comment: Thanks, that is interesting. The only way I can read the correct value within my `handleKeyPress` function is by adding `currPos` as a dependency to both `useEffect` functions.  

I will continue to investigate where the bug may be coming from

Comment: Yes, you'll have to include all dependent vars as a dependency. Sometimes to avoid making new copies of the same function, we use `useCallback` which memorizes the function call.

Answer (score 1):

The flow of your code is:
a) console.log the current position.
b) Update the value. You will see it effectively updated if you check the state with react developer tools.

Under this flow, the behavior you experience is correct.

To see the console.log every time you update the counter you will need to add an effect:

```
const [currPos, setCurrPos] = useState(0);
useEffect(()=>{
  console.log(`Current position is ${currPos}`);
}, [])
// Update currPos so next keyPress is in the correct position
setCurrPos((prevState) => prevState + 1);
```

This way, you will get the log AFTER its update and not before.

Answer (score 0):

**This is a duplicate answer:** [React Native console.log old value useState](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73430511/react-native-console-log-old-value-usestate/73430669#73430669)

The useState hook is somewhat asynchronous (although you cannot `wait` for it).

Try using a useEffect:

```js
useEffect(() => {
   console.log(isEnabled)
}, [isEnabled]) // Array of dependencies: when any of these value changes, the function in the useEffect will re-run
```

More information here:

- https://dev.to/shareef/react-usestate-hook-is-asynchronous-1hia
- https://javascript.plainenglish.io/why-you-shouldnt-always-use-usestate-658994693018

Answer (score 0):

Generally you can only able to see the state default after changing the state . So there is two possible way to check the current position .
First one is :

```
const [currPos, setCurrPos] = useState(0);    
useEffect(() => console.log(currPos), [currPos]);    
setCurrPos(prevCurrPos => prevCurrPos + 1);
```

That Answer by @Jaisal Shah Kudos to him

And Secound Way is  :

```
const [currPos, setCurrPos] = useState(0);
    
myFunction() {
  setCurrPos(prevCurrPos => prevCurrPos + 1);
} 
      
useEffect(()=>{
   myFunction();
   console.log(currPos); // Then you can call your console and you may able to get it 
 },[])
```

after this you can put your console to check the position and while calling the set state . But Note that you can not get the updated state on console after just updating `usestate` . So just put console out of or in

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

Looking at your code I would say you are missing the return statement. Try this instead:

```
setCurrPos((prevState) => return prevState + 1);
```

Comment: Thia is not correct answer. It has `SyntaxError`. To return from a function you have to wrap your return statement in `{` and `}`. Else implicitely return like `setCurrPos((prevState) => prevState + 1);` which OP has already done it.

Comment: when using arrow function without curly brackets the expression after the arrow is returned by default. `setCurrPos((prevState) => prevState + 1);`  is the same as `setCurrPos((prevState) => { return prevState + 1 });`