# React Context API current

Tags: reactjs, react-context

Okay...what is happening here cause I don't undrestand? I have an react context api where I store the current user data. In the login function I console log the currentUser and everything looks fine, but then when I write the currentUser in chrome dev tools, it appears undefined. In localStorage I also have the data. What is happening? What am I doing wrong? Can someone, please help me.

[image]

Here is my code:

authContext.js

```
import { createContext, useState, useEffect } from "react";
import axios from "axios";

export const AuthContext = createContext();

export const AuthContextProvider = ({ children }) => {
  const [currentUser, setCurrentUser] = useState(
    JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("user")) || null
  );

  const login = async (inputs) => {
    try {
      const res = await axios.post("/login", inputs);
      setCurrentUser(res.data);
      console.log("res.data: ", res.data); //returns data
      console.log("currentUser ", currentUser); //returns data
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error);
    }
  };

  const logout = async () => {
    localStorage.clear();
    setCurrentUser(null);
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    localStorage.setItem("user", JSON.stringify(currentUser));
  }, [currentUser]);

  return (
    <AuthContext.Provider value={{ currentUser, login, logout }}>
      {children}
    </AuthContext.Provider>
  );
};
```

index.js

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom/client";
import { AuthContextProvider } from "./ccontext/authContext";
import App from "./App";
import "./index.css";

const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById("root"));
root.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <AuthContextProvider>
      <App />
    </AuthContextProvider>
  </React.StrictMode>
);
```

Login.jsx

```
/*...*/
const LoginForm = () => { 
  const [error, setError] = useState(null);
  const navigate = useNavigate();
  const { login } = useContext(AuthContext);

  const handleFormSubmit = (values, actions) => {
    try {
      login(values);
      actions.resetForm();
      navigate("/");
      console.log("logged in");
    } catch (err) {
      setError(err.response.data);
    }
  };
/*...*/
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Updating state is best seen **like** an asynchronous operation. You cannot set state in a function / effect and expect it to immediately be updated, on the spot. Well, it technically is, but you won't see the updates in your "already-running" function.

I am pretty sure that if you extract your log in the component root it will display the appropriate value after the login function finishes executing and the component properly sets the new state.

If you do need the value in the function you should directly use `res.data`.

**A deeper dive:**

Whenever your login function runs it forms a closure around your **current** values (including `currentUser` which is `undefined` at the moment).

When you update the `currentUser` in the login function you basically inform react that you need to update that value. It will handle this in the background, preparing the state for the next render, but your login function will keep running with whatever values it started with. Your "new" state values will not be available until you run the function again. This is because the already-running function "closed over" old values, so it can only reference those.

As a side note, if you use a `ref` for instance you would not have this problem. Why? Because refs do not participate in the react lifecycle. When you modify a `ref` it changes on the spot. You will have the updated value precisely on the next line. State does not work like that, it is coupled to the component lifecycle, so it will update on the next render.

Comment: thanks for yout answer. can you please explain to me how to use ref?

Comment: https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#useref

You can use this inside your effects / callbacks without adding it to the deps array and will always have the fresh value at your disposal.

This is useful when you need to reference values in your effects without them re-triggering the effect when changing.

I need to emphasize though that this doesn't look like a solution for your situation. I would not use a ref in your example, but simply directly log the value (res.data), not the state.

Comment: If you use a ref instead of state for currentUser then the effect that sets the user in local storage would not trigger when currentUser changes, which is precisely what you don't want.

Comment: sorry, but i don't quite understand. what I need is that when the user logs in, to somehow set the currentUser object so I can use it through my entire application, because I have to render some components only if user is logged in and display some of the currentUser informations, like the name or the email. okay, I understood why I can't set the currentUser using useState, but I don't undrestand your aproach.

Comment: You can and should set the state there, it is ok. Only the console.log is not functioning properly. Can you please try to move the console.log immediately after the useState hook (outside the login function) and see if it logs the appropriate value?

Comment: yes, it logs accordingly. thank you so much for your time, help and explanations!!!